# Groovy Jsonslurper edit value in array

Tags: json, groovy

i searched and tried out a lot of things to solve my problem. But it seems that nothing will work. Maybe I just understand it wrong. I have a test.json File looking like this.

```
{
    "TEST-A":             [{ "app_id":"aaa" }],
    "TEST-B":              [{ "app_id":"bbb" }],
    "TEST-C":          [{ "app_id":"ccc" }]
}
```

and now i want to edit TEST-B with "xxx". What am i trying for example ist:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def inputFile = new File("../config/test.json")
def inputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text)
def builder = new JsonBuilder(inputJSON)

builder.content.TEST-B[0] = 'xxx'
```

I thought that i already have a map to edit or do i need to use "assert"?

Greetings Frost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
import groovy.json.*

def data = '''\
{
    "TEST-A":   [{ "app_id":"aaa" }],
    "TEST-B":   [{ "app_id":"bbb" }],
    "TEST-C":   [{ "app_id":"ccc" }]
}'''

def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(data)
println "parsed is a java.util.Map: ${parsed instanceof Map}"

parsed.'TEST-B'[0].app_id = 'xxx'

println "map after change: $parsed"

def result = JsonOutput.toJson(parsed)
println "result is a String: ${result instanceof String}"

println "result: $result"
println "pretty result:\n${JsonOutput.prettyPrint(result)}"
```

when run, prints out:

```
~> groovy test.groovy
parsed is a java.util.Map: true
map after change: [TEST-A:[[app_id:aaa]], TEST-B:[[app_id:xxx]], TEST-C:[[app_id:ccc]]]
result is a String: true
result: {"TEST-A":[{"app_id":"aaa"}],"TEST-B":[{"app_id":"xxx"}],"TEST-C":[{"app_id":"ccc"}]}
pretty result:
{
    "TEST-A": [
        {
            "app_id": "aaa"
        }
    ],
    "TEST-B": [
        {
            "app_id": "xxx"
        }
    ],
    "TEST-C": [
        {
            "app_id": "ccc"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I believe accomplishes the essence of what you are trying to do. The thing to understand about JsonSlurper is after parsing the in-data, what you get back is a normal `java.util.Map` (or possibly a `java.util.List` depending on the in-data json).

In other words, the `parsed` variable above is just a Map where the keys are strings and the values are Lists of Maps.

The second thing to keep in mind is that keys like `TEST-B` are not valid indentifiers in groovy so you can not just write `parsed.TEST-B` because that would be interpreted as `parsed.TEST` `-` `B`, so you have to quote keys with special characters like this.

After you change the map and assuming you want to get back to a json representation, you have to use something like JsonOutput as in the code above.

Comment: That worked, also many thx for the explanation. That helped me.